# TCAs (total combinatory algebras) with oracles

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

Is there a natural, non-trivial example of a TCA (total combinatory algebra, cf. pca) with a natural notion of an oracle?

Comment: Bob, could you provide a little more background on TCA's, or a link where we can find out more? Is this post relevant: http://mathoverflow.net/a/57489/1946?

Comment: A reference on TCAs: http://janwillemklop.nl/Jan_Willem_Klop/Bibliography_files/89.extendingpca.pdf

Comment: Joel, those are some great references. I don't know of any standard reference. Pca's are used in realizability, so any reference work including realizability would have to talk about them. They're in Beeson's book, and likely van Oosten's "Realizability." I'd think they'd be in any good book on the lambda-calculus too.

Comment: I'm surprised that Andrej's suggestion of just defining "divergence" as 42 (with the Turing functions, K_1) actually works. So that's not a bad example, but noticeably unnatural, even if just in that one spot.